# Hibernate/JPA get value of column with default value in database after merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

**Case:** I want to get value of field which is mapped to column with default value on database side after I merge object.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`OBJECT` (
  `OBJECT_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` VARCHAR(64) NULL,
  `CREATED_ON` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `EDITED_ON` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

**Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OBJECT")
public class SomeObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp createdOn;
    private Timestamp editedOn;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Timestamp createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "EDITED_ON", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Timestamp getEditedOn() {
        return editedOn;
    }

    public void setEditedOn(Timestamp editedOn) {
        this.editedOn = editedOn;
    }
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Transactional
public class ObjectDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public someObject merge(someObject someObject) {
        return entityManager.merge(someObject);
    }
}
```

**What I want to do:**

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
someObject.setName("name");
SomeObject insertedObject = objectDAO.merge(someObject);
System.out.println(insertedObject.getId());
System.out.println(insertedObject.getEditedOn());
```

**Result:**
object is inserted into database, all default values are generated properly.

**Question:**
Why second println prints null, but first println prints proper value of Id which was inserted into database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I found that if I use default database values it is not possible to have them in entity returned from merge. Simple as that. I change apporach and I use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` annotations. This is how it should be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OBJECT")
public class SomeObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp createdOn;
    private Timestamp editedOn;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Timestamp createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "EDITED_ON")
    public Timestamp getEditedOn() {
        return editedOn;
    }

    public void setEditedOn(Timestamp editedOn) {
        this.editedOn = editedOn;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void setDates() {
        createdOn = LocalDateTime.now();
        editedOn = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void setEditedOn() {
        editedOn = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

And why proper id was in returned entity? Because it is actually generated by Hibernate `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Answer (score 1):

Before you execute this line:

> System.out.println(insertedObject.getEditedOn());

you must "flush" (synchronize) your updates by calling: `entityManager.flush();`